# QML Different performance between run-time load font and embed font into qrc

Tags: qt, fonts, qml

My Environment:

```
Qt: 5.3.1 
OS: Windows7
```

I use `QApplication::setFont(myFont)` to change `myFont` as default font for QML.

There is two way to load the font file.

```
//1. Load from qrc
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(QStringLiteral(":/myFont.otf"))

//2. Load from local file
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(QStringLiteral("myFont.otf"))
```

Problem is:

The first one display **bold** `Text`.

The second one does not display **bold** `Text`

The same font, but why different performance?
QML code is exactly same. I confirmed the font was correctly loaded by this:

```
Component.onCompleted: console.log(font.family)
```

The output is same.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @derM Sorry, I updated my question. Using different way load font, got different performance.